# CSS counter: Skip OL nested inside of another OL

Tags: html, css

I am running into a problem where a WYSIWYG editor I'm using creates sub-items in lists by creating a new `ol` inside of the parent `ol` instead of inside of the parent `li`, making it difficult for me to understand how to get the counter to recognize Item 3 as 3 instead of 4. I realize the proper way to do this would be to nest the `ol` into the `li` but this editor just doesn't want to do that, and I have people who do not know HTML using the editor to make lists.

I've tried .articlecontainer ol ol { counter-increment: none } thinking it would skip counting the nested OL, however for reasons that are beyond me right now, it is counting the third LI as part of the OL that it's not even a child of (I think.)

```css
.articlecontainer ol li {
  line-height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.articlecontainer ol li:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: 25px;
  /* was 50% */
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  height: 2em;
  background: #F7941E;
  width: 2em;
  border: .3em solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  line-height: 24px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  color: white;
}

.articlecontainer ol {
  counter-reset: li;
}

.articlecontainer ol li:hover {
  background: #f7941e;
}
```

```html
<div class="articlecontainer">
  <ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <ol>
      <li>Sub-item 1</li>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>Sub-item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is make use of the **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** to ensure that your selectors only target the immediate children of the desired elements. In your case, you're looking to apply two child combinators; one to ensure that the `ol` elements are the direct child of `.articlecontainer`, and another to ensure that the `li` elements are the direct children of those `ol` elements:

```css
.articlecontainer > ol > li {
    line-height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.articlecontainer > ol > li:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 25px; /* was 50% */
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #F7941E;
    width: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    line-height: 24px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    color: white;
}

.articlecontainer > ol {
    counter-reset: li;
}

.articlecontainer > ol > li:hover {
    background: #f7941e;
}
```

```html
<div class="articlecontainer">
  <ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <ol>
      <li>Sub-item 1</li>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>Sub-item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

As for your comment regarding the markup restructure, note that the `<ol>` element **[only allows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)** `<li>` elements as direct children. If you want to have sub-menus, they **must** reside inside of parent `<li>` elements (as `ol > li > ol > li`) in order to form valid markup.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` direct child selector when customizing your counter.

```css
.articlecontainer ol li {
    line-height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.articlecontainer > ol > li:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 25px; /* was 50% */
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #F7941E;
    width: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    line-height: 24px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    color: white;
}

.articlecontainer > ol {
    counter-reset: li;
}

.articlecontainer ol li:hover {
    background: #f7941e;
}
```

```html
<div class="articlecontainer">
  <ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <ol>
      <li>Sub-item 1</li>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>Sub-item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Serg, thanks so much! This caused me to realize that the problem was also that I was using the same counter for the nested OL. I finally got it fully working by creating a new counter for OL's nested within the parent OL, and giving LI's inside of those the same styling.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.